# PHP CURL - SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am creating XML in PHP and and sending the request using CURL.  I am getting back an error: SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport/operations/ProcessMessage.

My XML being sent with sensitive info x'd out:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tran="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport"> 
<soap:Header> 
  <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
    <wsse:UsernameToken> 
      <wsse:Username>x</wsse:Username> 
      <wsse:Password>x</wsse:Password> 
      <wsu:Created>x</wsu:Created> 
    </wsse:UsernameToken> 
  </wsse:Security> 
<tran:PayloadManifest> 
  <tran:manifest contentID="Content0" namespaceURI="?" element="?" relatedID="?" version="?"/> 
</tran:PayloadManifest> 
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body> 
  <tran:ProcessMessage> 
    <tran:payload> 
      <tran:content id="Content0"> 
        <Search> 
          <Deal> 
            <Code>x</Code> 
            <Number>x</Number> 
            <Name>x</Name> 
          </Deal> 
        <SearchParms> 
          <LastName>Doe</LastName> 
          <FirstName>John</FirstName> 
        </SearchParms> 
      </Search> 
      </tran:content> 
    </tran:payload> 
  </tran:ProcessMessage> 
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I am setting the SOAPAction header like this:

```
$headers = array('Content-type: text/xml', 'SOAPAction: "http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport/operations/ProcessMessage"');
```

I've googled and searched SO and found a lot of questions with this error,  but nothing that seemed to help me.  Any ideas why I would be getting this error?

Comment: Should this URI resolve? http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport/operations/ProcessMessage Does not for me.

Comment: I don't really know the gritty details of how SOAP works, but I assumed it didn't have to resolve in a browser to be a valid web service/soap address.

Comment: I'd concur. Ages since I've had to use SOAP. Any reason to not use an actual SOAP client like NuSOAP or PHP's client?

Comment: Am I conflating things or does this have anything to do with "standards for technology and automotive retail"? Singular... https://www.starstandard.org/ Or wrong STAR?

Comment: Yes, that is what the Star Standards are.

Comment: Looks like you've got the domain wrong... or something broke on their end... whois does show `changed: 2019-08-21`. They offer any support or discussion board? Also, maybe drop the soap and look if they now offer the JSON Rest API they talk about having started to develop in 2018.

Comment: Can you show me the link that you are seeing that info on the URL?  Unfortunately, my boss says this is the method we have to use so I can't switch to anything else.

Comment: I was just doing #whois ... from the command line. But I mean... https://web.archive.org/web/20110905073402/http://starstandards.org/ Makes it seem like they moved things from starstandards.org to starstandard.org.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198961/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-dmikester1).